# Asp .Net Linkbutton event firing when javascript event handler is assigned

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a linkbuton in a asp .net aspx page. I open that page using jquery ui dialog in another page.

From the code that opens the page I put an event handler on a button in the newly opened page to close the page.

My problem is that the event triggers even if the button isn't clicked. My window appears for a second and then disappears.

Here is my code:

```
            if (hdnShowVote.val() == "True" && vote == null) {
            $("#divModal1").dialog({ height: 500, width: 800, modal: true, hide: "fade", closeOnEscape: true, closeText: "", title: "Vote", dialogClass: 'modalBare' })
            $("#ifrVote").attr("src", "CustomerVote.aspx");
            $("#ifrVote").ready(function () {
                $("#ifrVote").contents().find("#btnClose_CustomerVote").click(closeVote());
                alert($("#ifrVote").contents().find("body").length);
            });
        }
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are setting your function to execute on the document.ready of the page referred to as `$("#ifrVote")`